# Why does webpack bundle browser atob inside my umd module?

Tags: webpack

I am bundling a Typescript project as an UMD module through webpack. When I import such a module inside a separate node application, the application fails with:

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

Not that my webpack output `globalObject` is already `this`. The offending code seems to be the following:

```
/***/ "./node_modules/atob/browser-atob.js":
/*!*******************************************!*\
  !*** ./node_modules/atob/browser-atob.js ***!
  \*******************************************/
/*! no static exports found */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

/* WEBPACK VAR INJECTION */(function(Buffer, module) {(function (w) {
  "use strict";

  function findBest(atobNative) {
    // normal window
    if ('function' === typeof atobNative) { return atobNative; }


    // browserify (web worker)
    if ('function' === typeof Buffer) {
      return function atobBrowserify(a) {
        //!! Deliberately using an API that's deprecated in node.js because
        //!! this file is for browsers and we expect them to cope with it.
        //!! Discussion: github.com/node-browser-compat/atob/pull/9
        return new Buffer(a, 'base64').toString('binary');
      };
    }

    // ios web worker with base64js
    if ('object' === typeof w.base64js) {
      // bufferToBinaryString
      // https://git.coolaj86.com/coolaj86/unibabel.js/blob/master/index.js#L50
      return function atobWebWorker_iOS(a) {
        var buf = w.base64js.b64ToByteArray(a);
        return Array.prototype.map.call(buf, function (ch) {
          return String.fromCharCode(ch);
        }).join('');
      };
    }

        return function () {
            // ios web worker without base64js
            throw new Error("You're probably in an old browser or an iOS webworker." +
                " It might help to include beatgammit's base64-js.");
    };
  }

  var atobBest = findBest(w.atob);
  w.atob = atobBest;

  if ((typeof module === 'object') && module && module.exports) {
    module.exports = atobBest;
  }
}(window));
```

Why does webpack bundle browser-atob.js instead of node-atob.js?

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem, and for us it was related to *our own dependency* on:

https://git.coolaj86.com/coolaj86/atob.js/src/branch/master/browser-atob.js

If you don't depend on that directly, check that none of your dependencies' dependencies have it :)

As a fix, we're using (in coffeescript):

```
if process?
  # for node case
  atob = (input) -> Buffer.from(input, 'base64').toString('binary')
  btoa = (input) -> Buffer.from(input).toString('base64')
else
  # for browser/webworker
  atob = self.atob
  btoa = self.btoa
```

which should work for node, browser, and webworker cases. In JS:

```
if (typeof process !== "undefined" && process !== null) {
  // for node case
  atob = function(input) {
    return Buffer.from(input, 'base64').toString('binary');
  };
  btoa = function(input) {
    return Buffer.from(input).toString('base64');
  };
} else {
  // for browser/webworker
  atob = self.atob;
  btoa = self.btoa;
}
```